# Skip the Form.SizeChanged event at start

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this event handler:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But I don't want that it will be called at the start (only when the user changes the size).
Is this possible?

Comment: Are you changing the size of the Form, in code, when it's first loaded? You can handle `ResizeEnd` instead.

Comment: size of the form

Comment: its called before Form_Load()

Comment: @Jimi One downside of the `ResizeEnd` event is that it also gets triggered when the form is moved.

Comment: @41686d6564 True, but nobody stops you from checking the current Size and Location when the event is raised (coupled with `ResizeBegin`).

Comment: Add the event handler in `Form.Shown`

Comment: It doesn't raise at start, unless you have changed the size manually in `Load` or set it in a base from or changed designer generated code or something. For each control and form, designer generates their event handler codes after their property codes, it basically means at the time of setting the `ClientSize` property or `WindowState`, still `this.SizeChanged+=...` has not been registered.

Comment: @Tim593 May I know what's is causing the issue here? Is it one of the cases that I mentioned in the previous comment or something else? The Question/Answer IMO is misleading in the current format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a boolean field called `_formLoaded` and set it to false. When the form is loaded, set it to true.

Then, in the `SizeChanged` event handler, start with:

```
if (_formLoaded)
```